# Insert a row that duplicates the previous row (month) into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I want to do is duplicate the previous row if it is missing a month of data for that location. While adding a column that would add a a date for that month that was missing. For example if it was missing September the it would put 9/1/2018 in the new column.

So a little background I am looking at collections information for a ton of different locations that for the most part are collected on each month. But sometimes there isn't collections in a certain month and in that case we want to duplicate the data for the missing month from the previous month. I was thinking I could find the months that missed a collect by creating the `Month Diff` column. Then I just need to insert one row per month diff. So if there is a difference of 3 months then I would insert three new rows and have the additional column that would give them a date for that month.

Here is the code I have so far but I am stuck on adding in the rows and I am not sure if this is even possible.

```
Select  
  Location_ID, 
  Convert(Date,CONVERT(varchar(10),Collect_Month_Key,101)) as Collect_Date, 
  Calc_Gross_Totals, 
  Loc_Country, 
  CONVERT(varchar(8),Collect_Month_Key)+'-'+Location_ID as [Unique Key],
  MONTH(Convert(Date,CONVERT(varchar(10),Collect_Month_Key,101))) as MONTH, 
  YEAR(Convert(Date,CONVERT(varchar(10),Collect_Month_Key,101))) as 'YEAR',
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location_ID+'-'+left(Collect_Month_Key,4) ORDER BY Collect_Month_Key ASC)  as 'INDEX',
Cast(
    Case 
        when MONTH(Convert(Date,CONVERT(varchar(10),Collect_Month_Key,101))) > ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location_ID+'-'+left(Collect_Month_Key,4) ORDER BY Collect_Month_Key ASC) 
        Then MONTH(Convert(Date,CONVERT(varchar(10),Collect_Month_Key,101))) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location_ID+'-'+left(Collect_Month_Key,4) ORDER BY Collect_Month_Key ASC) 
        Else 0 
    End as bit) as 'Month Diff'
From FT_GPM_NPM_CYCLES AS cyc
INNER JOIN LU_Location AS loc ON cyc.Lu_Loc_Key = loc.LU_Loc_Key
INNER JOIN LU_Loc_Country AS cty ON loc.LU_Loc_Country_Key = cty.LU_Loc_Country_Key
Where 
  Collect_Month_Key <> -1 and 
  Convert(Date,CONVERT(varchar(10),Collect_Month_Key,101)) >= '2016-1-1'
Order By 
  Location_ID, 
Collect_Date;`
```

Attached is my output as an image to give an idea of what it should look like.

[image: Picture of my query output]

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Comment: Yes it did help a little bit. I am still trying to implement everything though! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, a hint at getting the full list of months -- you can use recursive CTE for that, see top of example. 2018 date is the first month, 2020-01-01 is the first month you **don't** want to see on your chart.

Second CTE is dummy "actual report data, just the months where it exists". Skip over that for now.

Once you have a complete list of months, use the datediff condition similar to the example below to help you with OUTER joining this dimension to your data table. You only need the report date at this stage, not the data columns.

Now you can use window function to figure out which month would have the data for the outer-join-misses (see `MAX ... OVER ...` clause below). Note that this uses a default behaviour of this window function -- MAX over previous rows.

Next you just have to join back to the original data, including the data columns.

Example:

```
WITH all_months(monthStart) AS (
    SELECT CAST('2018-01-01' AS date)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, monthStart)
     FROM all_months
     WHERE DATEADD(month, 1, monthStart) < '2020-01-01'
    )
, cte_data as (
    select /* LocationID, */ DATEADD(day, 3, monthStart) as reportDate, 'zum-zum_data_'+CAST(monthStart as varchar) as actual_data
from all_months
WHERE datediff(month, SYSDATETIME(), monthStart) %3 =0 
)
, cte_data_join as (
select /* LocationID, */ monthStart, reportDate 
from all_months
    LEFT JOIN cte_data ON (datediff(month, cte_data.reportDate, all_months.monthStart )= 0) 
)

, cte_month_source as (
select *, max(report_date) 
            over (/* PARTITION BY LocationID*/ order by monthStart) as source_date
from cte_data_join
)

select /* LocationID, */ cte_month_source.monthStart as reporting_month, source_date as report_data_date, actual_data
from cte_month_source 
join cte_data ON (cte_month_source.source_date = cte_data.reportDate) 
ORDER BY monthStart
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I am just getting a change to look at it now and I think it is making sense. Let me try implementing it in my query and I am sure I will have some questions.

Comment: Why did you put 'zum-zum_data_' in before + cast? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: **zum-zum_data** is just random words here. The whole cte_data subquery should really be replaced with the query calling your actual data.
The **actual_data** column in the last part of the query should be replaced with the columns from your tables.

Did you try running the example query as is ? You can take the first two CTEs and then add **select * from cte_data** to see the intermediate progress results.

Comment: Okay, yeah I was trying to run your query and I think I was confused with the `Location_ID` everywhere. So just to make sure I am on the same page for `CTE_DATA` I want to add all of my data to that statement. Then the `CTE_JOIN` is where I join my dates with the list of the the months. Then what is the `CTE_MONTH_SOURCE` part for? And then the last select statement  is what I am outputting from my different cte tables. Also what is this saying `WHERE datediff(month, SYSDATETIME(), monthStart) %3 =0 ` with the `%3=0`. Thank you so much.

Comment: So I think I am really close to getting this but I am getting this error in my last cte statement "Incorrect syntax near 'order'-" and here is my current code `Month_Source(Join_data)`
`As(Select max(Collect_Date) over(PARTITION BY LocationID order by monthStart)`
`From CollectDate, LocationData)`

Comment: well, the syntax seems to be incorrect. First of all -- where is the join condition?
then -- your query seem to be returning just one column. How are you going to join it to anything else? Third -- I have no idea what are the structures of your FROM tables, so I can't really say anything about those.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your example to focus on the collection date and audit year/month. Collection date detail is what is being duplicated when the audit year/month doesn't exist.

```
begin
    -- simplified table
    create table    #collect    (
                                    Coll_Dt     date
                                    ,Val        int
                                    ,Aud_Yr     int
                                    ,Aud_Mth    int
                                )

    -- adding data
    insert into #collect
    values       ('2018-01-01',1,2018,1)
                ,('2018-02-01',2,2018,2)
                ,('2018-03-01',3,2018,3)
                ,('2018-05-01',5,2018,5)
                ,('2018-06-01',6,2018,6)
                ,('2018-07-01',7,2018,7)
                ,('2018-08-01',8,2018,8)
                ,('2018-12-01',12,2018,12)


    -- adding row number to determine where listing starts
    select      row_number() over (order by aud_yr,aud_mth) pid
                ,*
    into        #wrk
    from        #collect

end


declare @i      int = 1
        ,@i2    int
        ,@max   int = (select max(pid) from #wrk)
        ,@diff  int
        ,@rows  int

while @i <= @max
begin

    -- if @i = 1 then it is the first record and there's nothing to compare to
    if @i > 1
    begin
        -- determining the difference between current and prior collections
        select      @diff = datediff(month,b.coll_dt,a.coll_dt)
        from        #wrk    a
        outer apply (
                        select      top 1
                                    *
                        from        #wrk    b
                        where       b.Coll_Dt < a.Coll_Dt
                        order by    b.Coll_Dt desc
                    )       b
        where       a.pid = @i

        if @diff > 1
        begin
            -- number of rows to be added
            set @rows = @diff - 1

            -- resetting incrementor
            set @i2 = 1

            -- adding new rows
            while @i2 <= @rows
            begin
                insert into #collect
                select      Coll_Dt
                            ,Val
                            ,year(dateadd(month,@i2 * -1,coll_dt))
                            ,month(dateadd(month,@i2 * -1,coll_dt))
                from        #wrk
                where       pid = @i


                -- incrementing to exit loop and add additional rows, if more than 1 row is needed
                set @i2 = @i2 + 1
            end

        end

    end

    -- incrementing loop
    set @i = @i +1
end

select * from #collect order by aud_yr, aud_Mth


-- cleaning db
drop table  #collect
            ,#wrk
```